# Default Expiration Time of Cacheable Resources

Tags: http

I was looking for some website optimization tips online and most of them had a common tip of specifying expiration of Cacheable resources. I have not yet specified the expiration. So what would be the default expiration duration the cacheable resources taking? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I am not sure how this particular question relates to google bigquery. Maybe there is some information you didn't disclose?

update: after your comment and the change of category to HTTP I think I can already answer.

If you are not setting any expires or cache-control headers, then a well-behaved browser should issue a new GET request every time. There is not such thing as a default expiration.

Depending on your technology stack, it might be possible that your web server or your application server add default cache headers. To verify that, you can just open the page on firefox/chrome with the developer tools and inspect the headers. If you can't find any "Expires" or "Cache-control" headers in the response your page is sending, then you don't have any default expiration and you are not making use of caching.

Comment: I am taking about the google's option for leverage browser caching for optimized caching "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching"